# Replacing string with substring using NSRegularExpression in Swift

Tags: swift, nsregularexpression

I'm very confused using Swift's regular expression for replacing strings.
I want to replace `<blubb>Test</blubb>` which does not work as expected:

```
let html  = "Test\r\nTest\r\nTest\r\nTest\r\nTest\r\nTest\r\nTest-<blubb>Test</blubb>-Test"
do {
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\<blubb\\>[\\s\\S]*\\<\\/blubb\\>", options: NSRegularExpression.Options.caseInsensitive)
    let range = NSMakeRange(0, html.count)
    let modString = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: html, options: [], range: range, withTemplate: "REPLACED")
    print( modString)
} catch {}
```

Result (not replacing string):

```
Test
Test
Test
Test
Test
Test
Test-<blubb>Test</blubb>-Test
```

**But:**

- If I remove all `\r` it works
- If I remove first `Test\r\n` it works too

Result of removing first Test\r\n:

```
Test
Test
Test
Test
Test
Test-REPLACED-Test
```

So am I missing something or is this a bug in the regex-engine used by Swift?

Comment: The reason – as explained in the duplicate Q&A – is that `html.count` is the “wrong count” for an NSRange. Use `html.utf16.count` or (better) the dedicated constructor `let range = NSRange(html.startIndex..., in: html)`

Comment: In your case `\r\n` counts as a single Swift Character, but as two `NSString` characters, so that `html.count` is “too small.”